# Replace a javascript file on all websites in WHM

Tags: shell, whm

I am having a serious issue. I need to replace a javascript file with a new one on all the websites in my WHM. I have almost 400 websites in my WHM and replacing it manually in every websites file manager is not possible.

I have no idea if that is possible or not, or how is that possible.

Is there a way to replace a particular js file with a new js file on all the websites in my WHM at one go through some shell script or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible from a linux shell prompt using a bash script (of course you can use any other type of script like perl/python or even php).

Let's say you save your new javascript code in a file called new.js. Then you could do a search through all your website (assuming the javascript file you want to be replaced is the same on all your accounts).

```
for i in `find /home/*/public_html/javscript-file.js`; do cat /path/to/new.js > $i; done
```

I can't guarantee you the code is actually working but these would be the basics (that will overwrite your actual javascript file with the content of the new.js file).

If you need only to replace some specific stuff from your .js file then you might need to use **sed** or **awk** or other specific text manipulation linux tools.

After that you will need another script that will search for the javascript file location in each of your cpanel users and sets the right permissions to that file (basically that file's permission should be cpaneluser:cpaneluser and 640 for chmod).